# Allow arbitrary user to read MonetDB's sys.queue

Tags: monetdb

I created a user *foouser* and a schema *fooschema* with some tables in it. *Foouser* executes long-running queries to its tables in *fooschema*.

Now I'd like to check on the status of the queries. However, *foouser* does not have sufficient permissions to access `sys.queue` table/view:

```
sql>SELECT * FROM sys.queue;
SELECT: access denied for foouser to table 'sys.queue'
sql>SELECT * FROM sys.queue();
SELECT: no such operator 'queue'
```

The *monetdb* user has the necessary permissions, but does not see *foosuer*'s queries but only their own:

```
sql>SELECT * FROM sys.queue;
+---------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------------------------+
| qtag    | user    | started                    | estimate                   | progress | status  | tag       | query                    |
+=========+=========+============================+============================+==========+=========+===========+==========================+
| 2593257 | monetdb | 2018-04-26 15:06:01.000000 | null                       |     null | running | 2593257@0 | select * from sys.queue; |
+---------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

So the question is: How can *foouser* view the status of its own queries? Can I grant *foouser* the access to `sys.queue()`? If so, how?

Comment: Any solution for this , even i am facing the same issue now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution so far. The problem hits me every now and then, and I keep ignoring it. ;-) Maybe you could write something on one of the [MonetDB mailing lists](https://www.monetdb.org/Developers/Mailinglists)?

Comment: The fact that the "superuser" *monetdb* does not see other user's queries has been reported as [MonetDB bug 6636](https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6636) recently.

Comment: MonetDB bug 6636 has been resolved on 29 Jan 2019 in [changeset 68191](https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB?cmd=changeset;node=f06ab9e5f30b). As the lastest release of MonetDB is younger than than, the fix is probably already included. Nevertheless, the change does only enable the sysadmin to see all user's queries (instead of just its own). However, the change does not allow an arbitrary user to access `sys.queue()` to see its own queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which allows a "normal" user to read its own `sys.queue`. However, this approach grants (for my liking) way to many permissions to the user and is therefore not optimal.

The approach is to grant the role *sysadmin* to *foouser*. This has to be done while being logged in as *monetdb* user (i.e. running `mclient -u monetdb`):

```
sql> grant sysadmin to foouser;
operation successful
```

Afterwards, if you log in as *foouser* (i.e. `mclient -u foouser`), you have to select the sysadmin role and can now see you own running queries by looking into `sys.queue`:

```
sql>set role sysadmin;
operation successful
sql>select * from sys.queue;
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| qtag    | user    | started     | estimate    | prog | status  | tag       | query        |
:         :         :             :             : ress :         :           :              :
+=========+=========+=============+=============+======+=========+===========+==============+
| 1627134 | foouser | 2018-11-09  | null        | null | running | 1627134@0 | insert into  |
:         :         : 17:48:57.00 :             :      :         :           : REDACTED     :
:         :         : 0000        :             :      :         :           : REDACTED     :
| 1627135 | foouser | 2018-11-09  | null        | null | running | 1627135@0 | select * fro |
:         :         : 17:48:57.00 :             :      :         :           : m sys.queue; :
:         :         : 0000        :             :      :         :           :              :
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
2 tuples !1 field truncated!
```

However, now the (intentionally) restricted user *foouser* has full administrative permissions what makes the use of a restricted user somewhat pointless.